# Check authenticity of file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have ansible role that downloads a script file, how can i check the authenticity of the file using md5sum before executing?

```
- name: Add xx official repository for ubuntu/debain
  get_url:
     url:  https://script.deb.sh
     dest: /opt/script.db.sh

- name: Execute the script
  script: /opt/script.db.sh
```

- i want to check the authenticity before downloading the file - can this be achieved in ansible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're not using the get_url option, after the file is in the location, call the `stat` module using the `get_checksum` option as [documented here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/stat_module.html#id2).

```
- name: Get sha256 sum of script
  stat:
    path: /opt/script.db.sh
    checksum_algorithm: sha256
    get_checksum: yes
  register: shell_stat

- name: Verify sha256sum of script before execution.
  fail:
    msg: "Failure, file is not correct."
  when: shell_stat.stat.checksum != '19d6105fa1a581cf3ad38f67080b6d55cb152b5441ae8bdf194e593f292f31e9'

- name: Execute the script
  script: /opt/script.db.sh
```

Update the sum on the `when:` line to match the file you expect.

Generating the checksum (sha256 in this example) vary on your operating system.  On most Linux distributions use the `sha256sum {filename}` command, on OSX, use `shasum -a 256 {filename}`.

Comment: is there any way to check the file authenticity before downloading?

Comment: @Swat: *You* will need to confirm that the file you're pushing out to your systems is the one you want.  Once you know that the file is ok, then generate the checksum of it to ensure you only install that file.  Remember, if the file is not in your control and someone else changes the file you're downloading in any way the checksum will change and your playbook will report the failure.  This is a *good thing* - it forces you and your team to re-verify the file and approve the file by updating the checksum in the playbook.

Answer (score 2):

`get_url` has a checksum parameter that you could use.

```
- name: Add xx official repository for ubuntu/debain
  get_url:
    url:  https://script.deb.sh
    dest: /opt/script.db.sh
    checksum: md5:1234
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/get_url_module.html

Comment: i tried this but getting an error 
- command: cksum /opt/script.db.sh
  register: md5_value

- name: checking the md5checksome
  get_url:
      url: https://script.deb.sh
      dest: /opt/script.db.sh
      checksum: md5:{{ md5_value }}
      force: true
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The checksum parameter has to be in format <algorithm>:<checksum>"}

Comment: AFAIK you can't use the CRC checksum in the `get_url` module.  `md5sum` will work however.  You will also need to specify the algorithm in the `checksum` parameter (i.e. - `checksum: "md5:{{ md5_value }}"`)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the "**checksum**" parameter "**get_url**" module. I show you an example of a playbook that executes a "role" to download OpenJDK8 only if the **md5sum** is correct.

File: `playbook.yml`

```
---
- name: "Download binaries"
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
  - openjdk
```

File: `openjdk/tasks/main.yml`

```
- name: "Download OpenJDK {{ openjdk_version }} binaries"
  get_url:
    url: https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8u40/ri/{{ openjdk_file }}
    dest: "{{ download_destination }}"
    checksum: "{{ openjdk_md5 }}"
    mode: 0750
  tags:
    - always
```

File: `openjdk/vars/main.yml`

```
---
download_destination: /var/tmp
openjdk_version: "8u40-b25"
openjdk_file: "openjdk-{{ openjdk_version }}-linux-x64-10_feb_2015.tar.gz"
openjdk_md5: "md5: 4980716637f353cfb27467d57f2faf9b"
```

The available cryptographic algorithms in Ansible 2.7 are: **sha1**, **sha224**, **sha384**, **sha256**, **sha512**, **md5**.

It works for me, I hope for you too.